# BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error when trying to pass a `Parcelable` through an `Intent`.
Basically, I've implemented my class as `Parcelable`, but I can't pass the object to another activity because it crashes when reading it. I tried several answers for this problem, but none has helped me to solve this issue.

So far, this is my code for `WeatherData.java` (sorry, the class is a bit large):

```
public class WeatherData implements Parcelable {

private final static String ICON_ADDR = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/";

static class City implements Parcelable {
    String name;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("cityName", name);
        dest.writeBundle(bundle);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<City> CREATOR = new Creator<City>() {

        @Override
        public City createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            // read the bundle containing key value pairs from the parcel
            Bundle bundle = source.readBundle();

            // instantiate the forecast info using values from the bundle
            return new City(bundle.getString("cityName"));
        }

        @Override
        public City[] newArray(int size) {
            return new City[size];
        }

    };

    private City (String cityName) {
        name = cityName;
    }
}

static class Weather implements Parcelable {
    String description;
    String icon;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("description", description);
        bundle.putString("icon", icon);
        dest.writeBundle(bundle);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Weather> CREATOR = new Creator<Weather>() {

        @Override
        public Weather createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            // read the bundle containing key value pairs from the parcel
            Bundle bundle = source.readBundle();

            // instantiate the forecast info using values from the bundle
            return new Weather(bundle.getString("description"),
                    bundle.getString("icon"));
        }

        @Override
        public Weather[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Weather[size];
        }

    };

    private Weather (String description, String icon) {
        icon = icon;
        description = description;
    }

}

static class Temp implements Parcelable {
    float day;
    float min;
    float max;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putFloat("day", day);
        bundle.putFloat("min", min);
        bundle.putFloat("max", max);

        dest.writeBundle(bundle);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Temp> CREATOR = new Creator<Temp>() {

        @Override
        public Temp createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            // read the bundle containing key value pairs from the parcel
            Bundle bundle = source.readBundle();

            // instantiate the forecast info using values from the bundle
            return new Temp(bundle.getFloat("day"),
                    bundle.getFloat("min"), bundle.getFloat("max"));
        }

        @Override
        public Temp[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Temp[size];
        }

    };

    private Temp (float tDay, float tMin, float tMax) {
        day = tDay;
        min = tMin;
        max = tMax;
    }
}

static class ForecastInfo implements Parcelable {
    Temp temp;
    ArrayList<Weather> weather;

    String getTemperatureInCelsius() {
        float t = temp.day - 273.15f;
        return String.format("%.0f" + (char) 0x00B0, t);
    };

    public String getIconAddress() {
        return ICON_ADDR + weather.get(0).icon + ".png";
    };

    public String getDescription() {
        if (weather != null && weather.size() > 0)
            return weather.get(0).description;
        return null;
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    };

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putParcelable("temp", this.temp);
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("weatherList", this.weather);

        dest.writeBundle(bundle);
    };

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ForecastInfo> CREATOR = new Creator<ForecastInfo>() {

        @Override
        public ForecastInfo createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            // read the bundle containing key value pairs from the parcel
            Bundle bundle = source.readBundle();

            // instantiate the forecast info using values from the bundle
            return new ForecastInfo((Temp) bundle.get("temp"),
                    (ArrayList<Weather>) bundle.get("weatherList"));
        }

        @Override
        public ForecastInfo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ForecastInfo[size];
        }

    };

    private ForecastInfo (Temp temp, ArrayList<Weather> weatherList) {
        this.temp = temp;
        this.weather = weatherList;
    };
}

// Relevant data for WeatherData
// The city (which only has a name in it)
City city;
// The array of forecast info extracted from the JSON
ArrayList<ForecastInfo> list;

private WeatherData (City city, ArrayList<ForecastInfo> forecastList) {
    city = city;
    list = forecastList;
}

// A method that converts temperature from Kelvin degrees to Celsius
String getTemperatureInCelsius(int day) {
    return list.get(day).getTemperatureInCelsius();
}

// getIconAddress concatenates the base address and the specific code for
// the icon
public String getIconAddress(int day) {
    return list.get(day).getIconAddress();
}

public String getName() {
    return city.name;
}

public String getDescription(int day) {
    return list.get(day).getDescription();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // create a bundle for the key value pairs
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    // insert the key value pairs to the bundle
    bundle.putString("cityName", this.getName());
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("forecastList", this.list);

    // write the key value pairs to the parcel
    dest.writeBundle(bundle);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<WeatherData> CREATOR = new Creator<WeatherData>() {

    @Override
    public WeatherData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        // read the bundle containing key value pairs from the parcel
        Bundle bundle = source.readBundle();
        return new WeatherData(bundle.getString("cityName"),
                new ArrayList<ForecastInfo>());

    }

    @Override
    public WeatherData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new WeatherData[size];
    }

};

private WeatherData (String name, ArrayList<ForecastInfo> forecastInfos) {
    City cityNew = new City(name);
    city = cityNew;
    forecastInfos.add(new ForecastInfo(
            new Temp(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
            new ArrayList<Weather>()));
    list = forecastInfos;
}

private WeatherData (String name) {
    City cityNew = new City(name);
    city = cityNew;
}  
}
```

Then, in my `MainActivity`, I call the following function (sorry about the multiple calls to `setExtrasClassLoader`):

```
public void showDetails(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.setExtrasClassLoader(WeatherData.class.getClassLoader());
    intent.setExtrasClassLoader(WeatherData.ForecastInfo.class.getClassLoader());
    intent.setExtrasClassLoader(WeatherData.City.class.getClassLoader());
    intent.setExtrasClassLoader(WeatherData.Weather.class.getClassLoader());
    intent.setExtrasClassLoader(WeatherData.Temp.class.getClassLoader());
    intent.putExtra("bundleObject", weatherData.list);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

After that, I'm trying to get the content of the intent in the new activity inside the `onCreate` method by:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.setExtrasClassLoader(WeatherData.class.getClassLoader());
    intent.setExtrasClassLoader(WeatherData.ForecastInfo.class.getClassLoader());
    ArrayList<WeatherData.ForecastInfo> list = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("bundleObject");
```

If I pass `weatherData.getName()` instead of `weatherData.list` in `showDetails`, it works but just for the string name of the city. When I try to put an `ArrayList<ForecastInfo>`, it breaks and raises this error:

> Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling:
>   com.example.android.climapp.WeatherData$Temp
>                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2411)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2337) ...

Comment: I'm confused why you are using bundles inside a Parcelable

Comment: Plus, you don't seem to understand how the setExtrasClassLoader method works. There can only be one ClassLoader set, multiple calls to the method only will use the most recent.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
I solved this by adding:

`bundle.setClassLoader(ForecastInfo.class.getClassLoader());`

in the `createFromParcel` method!

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it, but your code would be significantly simplified if you used some other serialization method like Gson

Comment: Hey cricket, I'm using Gson to convert the Json to an instance of this large class. What are you suggesting? Thanks!

Comment: Is the JSON string too large to pass through an Intent? I was suggesting that you could use `intent.putExtra`  after converting  the class back to JSON, then parse it out on the other side.

Comment: What I am doing right now is to get the Json using Volley, and then I use Gson to convert it to an instance of `WeatherData`. As I need this new object in the first activity, I just thought it would be better if I pass this new object instead of the Json to the other activity. I think your idea solves this problem, but I would need to parse the Json twice. Is this what you suggested?

Comment: Your Parcelable code is just a little messy, no offense. That's why I think passing around the JSON string would be cleaner. But there is a 1MB limit, I think, to how large Intent Extras can be, so that's why I asked

Comment: It's a lot smaller than 1MB, but I'm not getting why passing the JSON would be better. I thought the functionality of GSON is that you can use it as a bridge between your class and the JSON. So you should define your class before translating the JSON. In other words, do you suggest that I should remove the `Parcelable` instance (leaving the class only) and just pass the JSON object among the activities, and do the GSON conversion inside each activity? This is my very first attempt to create an "interesting" app :P, and no problem, I know this code is a bit messy!

Comment: You already have a serialization format (JSON). Parcelables are just the native Android mechanism for passing data. By mixing the two, you're just adding unnecessary complexity. Just my opinion

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree. I'll change the code, it would be more simpler and cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

To anyone who is struggling with this issue, it's because the new `Bundle` inside the `createFromParcel` method doesn't know about the `ForecastInfo` class. Thus, it could be solved telling the bundle to load the data of the missing class through `setClassLoader` like this:

```
       @Override
            public WeatherData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                // read the bundle containing key value pairs from the parcel
                Bundle bundle = source.readBundle();
                bundle.setClassLoader(ForecastInfo.class.getClassLoader());
                // instantiate the weather using values from the bundle
bundle.getParcelable("forecastList"));
                return new WeatherData(bundle.getString("cityName"),
                        new ArrayList<ForecastInfo>());

            }
```